# EC2 Cannot connect to the endpoint URL: "https://secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running ubuntu and am looking to connect it to the SecretsManager service.

- This EC2 instance is connected to a IAM role that has `SecretsManagerReadWrite` permission.
- It is connected to a `VPC` which has "Enable DNS Resolution" selected.
- A VPC endpoint to `com.amazonaws.us-east-2.secretsmanager` was created.
- The Outbound rule for the EC2 instance is port range all, protocol all, destination 0.0.0.0/0.

When attempting to connect via boto3, I'm getting:

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"
```

Running `curl https://www.google.com` returns the google homepage.

Meanwhile running `curl secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`

returns:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

I can't seem to figure out how/why the secrets manager is not able to be resolved.

### EDIT

The `/etc/resolv.conf` file looks like:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search us-east-2.compute.internal
```

Comment: As I look the endpoint for secretmanager that you're trying to connect to is not resolving correctly. can you check if the DNS resolution for the VPC endpoint is enabled? you can verify this by going to the VPC endpoint configuration in the console and verifying that "Enable DNS resolution" is checked. And basically you can check by pinging the secretsmanager endpoint from the EC2 instance to see if it is reachable. or check that there are no network ACLs or security groups that blocks traffic to the endpoint. please check that the outbound rule is configured exactly and let me know.

Comment: The "Enable DNS resolution" option is selected. Running ping https://secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/
ping: https://secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/: Name or service not known. There are no security groups that block traffic.

Comment: then please get to the file, "/etc/resolv.conf" on your EC2 instance to see which DNS servers it uses. Here, please check that it uses the DNS servers that are associated with your VPC.

Comment: what do you see by running "systemd-resolve --status"?

Comment: Bunch of commented characters above, then:

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search us-east-2.compute.internal

Within the /etc/resolv.conf file

Comment: systemd-resolve --status results in systemd-resolve: command not found. Even after running sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved, which is a little strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253578/discussion-between-xuxianjin-and-dataswede).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround was:

Modifying the yaml config file located in the `/etc/netplan` directory to:

```
network:
      # OLD STUFF HERE
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Then running:

```
sudo netplan apply;
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf;
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf;
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved;
```

This doesn't feel like the correct way to really handle this- but it works, and allows the DNS resolution to switch.